# Read array-node with foreach, doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this array in a foreach-loop with the 'as' $train 
Now i want to read out the 'mat'-node.

I've tried this:

```
<?php

echo "<!-- ";

foreach ($train['mat'] as $mat) {
    echo "Mat:" . $mat . "";
}

echo " -->";
?>
```

But it gives a empty foreach result in mijn HTML-source, between the comments.

```
Array
(
    [status] => 0
    [via] => Utrecht C., Houten, Geldermalsen
    [bestemming] => Tiel
    [vleugels] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [stopstations] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [naam] => Vleuten
                                    [code] => VTN
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [naam] => Utrecht Terwijde
                                    [code] => UTT
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [naam] => Utrecht Leidsche Rijn
                                    [code] => UTLR
                                )

                        )

                    [bestemming] => Tiel
                    [mat] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SLT-4
                                    [1] => Tiel
                                    [2] => 2422
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SLT-4
                                    [1] => Tiel
                                    [2] => 2464
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [vervoerder] => NS
    [spoor] => 6
)
```

Comment: First of all, enable proper PHP error reporting, so that PHP can tell you when you try to access elements that don't even exist. If $train is supposed that array you have shown - that does not have an element with key `mat` on the top level. (And even if it was pointing to the `mat` element on the right level - that contains arrays itself again, and you can not output an array with echo, that will just give you the _word_ "array".)

Comment: what does the array `$train` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help.

But I think you need read more about [PHP Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and Array index

```
echo "<!-- ";
foreach($train['vleugels'][0]['mat'] as $mat) {
    echo "Mat:".$mat[2]."<br>";
}
echo " -->";
// <!-- 2422 2464 -->
```

Comment: @JackVonderberg And your array in thread is `$train` or `$data`?

Comment: @JackVonderberg So I think you should try step by step: `var_dump($train['vleugels']` => `var_dump($train['vleugels'][0])` => `var_dump($train['vleugels'][0]['mat'])` xD. And my source is correct.

Comment: Nope, Quỳnh Nguyễn.
I'm already in a foreach!
Read my comment here below for more code.

Comment: @JackVonderberg How do you think about vote my answer bro?

Comment: Thnx! .. ..    . . .